# Get variable from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery

So I am having some trouble with this code and need some help.  I am not great at anything javascript related so this has thrown me for a loop.  I have a select box with different locations.  Based on the location the user chooses, an input box appears with a specific number.  The php page works if I fill in the variable, but I cannot seem to get the variable to pass from one page to another.

Here is the front page callded Dropdown_test.php:

```
<body>

<label>
    <span>Office Location</span><br>
    <select name="office" id="office" onChange="loadDoc()">
        <option value="">Select Office Location</option>
        <option value="place1">Place 1</option>
        <option value="place2">Place 2</option>
        <option value="place3">Place 3</option>
        <option value="place4">Place 4</option>
    </select>
</label>
<div id="drawing"></div>
<script>
    function loadDoc(){
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var office = document.getElementsByName("office");
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("drawing").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "fetch_details.php?=q" +office, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Here is the fetch_details page:

```
$office=$_GET['office'];
$rowSQL = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX( DWG ) AS DWG FROM dwg WHERE 
Office='$office';");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rowSQL);
$largestNumber = $row[ 'DWG' ];
$pieces = explode("-", $largestNumber);
$digit = $pieces[ 2 ] + 1;
$result = $pieces[ 0 ] . "-" . $pieces[ 1 ] . "-" . $digit;
echo "<input type='text' value='$result'></input>";
```

The fetch_page works just fine with the database, but when I combine them I get an undefined index.  Any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Change: `xhttp.open("GET", "fetch_details.php?=q" +office, true);` to `xhttp.open("GET", "fetch_details.php?office=" +office, true);`.

Comment: try changing to this: `xhttp.open("GET", "fetch_details.php?=office" +office, true);`

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez you mean `'office=' + office`, right?

Comment: Why the clunky vanilla javascript when you have the jquery tag? I'm not seeing ANY jquery here.

Comment: I really would suggest if you just use the JQuery `AJAX` shortcuts, It would really make your life easier.

Comment: I edited the question, but just incase it was not a typo, java != javascript

Comment: @manix I tried that and still getting the undefined index.

Comment: You're assigning the entire `select` object, not the value.

Comment: @Toleo  Honestly I don't know why I am not using ajax, I have been having trouble wrapping my head around how any of the java types (javascrip, jquery, ajax) work, and I am to the point I just want this to work.

Comment: none of the things you mentioned are "java type".  java is an entirely different language that is not related to any of these things.  you are writing javascript.  jQuery is a javascript library.  ajax is a javascript mechanism for making web requests in javascript that do not involve browser transitions.

Comment: Yes, @u_mulder, the sintax is: `xhttp.open("GET", "fetch_details.php?office=" +office, true);`.

Comment: I put the equal sign in the correct place and it works.  Thank you for your help.  I know it isn't pretty right now but it is a start.

Comment: `ajax` is a process under javascript (ajax is not something all by itself). `jquery` is a library for javascript to make life much easier, especially when dealing with ajax.

Comment: Since I seem to be completely out of my depth when it comes to this part of design, is there a good place go to wrap my head around jquery and ajax?  I spent alot of time looking at w3schools but they are so simple I have a hard time ramping up to real world examples.

Comment: learn.jquery.com is a great place to start reading about the library.  There are also some introductory problems you can work at try.jquery.com for some hands on learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to your current problem is in fixing query string.

Query string looks like `name=value`.

Now you have `=namevalue`. This is **obviously** wrong.

So, fix is:

```
// first `q` (name) then `=`, then office (value)
xhttp.open("GET", "fetch_details.php?q=" +office, true);
```

And second - on server side you will recieve `$_GET['q']`, not `$_GET['office']`.

So, another fix is:

```
$office=$_GET['q'];
```

Or if you want:

```
$office=$_GET['office'];
```

then fix is:

```
// first `office` (name) then `=`, then office (value)
xhttp.open("GET", "fetch_details.php?office=" +office, true);
```

As stated in comments, string

```
var office = document.getElementsByName("office");
```

returns not what you expect. If you have an `id` - replace it with

```
var office = document.getElementById("office").value;
```

As already noticed in comments

- if you have `jquery` - use jquery, it will be simpler.
- protect agains sql-injections.

Comment: `var office = document.getElementsByName("office");` returns a NodeList and passing `office` in the query string isn't going to do anything.

Comment: @WildBeard, thanks, edited.

Comment: I did the updates you suggested and it is working great.  Thanks.